# IBM MQ Queue Manager CCSID

Tags: ibm-mq, aix

There is a queue manager which runs with CCSID 437, and i would like to connect remotely to the queue manager via MQ Explorer. I got this error:

AMQ6047E: Conversion not supported.
EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ is unable to convert string data tagged in CCSID 437 to data in CCSID
1208.

My first debugging try was connecting to the queue manager with mqsc console. And "alter qmgr ccsid(1208) force" even with this i couldn't connect. (i did a restart). And the issue was the same.

However, i seen another queue manager which runs with ccsid (819), but there wasn 't any issue with connecting.

IBM MQ version 9.1
OS: AIX 7.1

Any idea that can solve this issue?
If i change ccsid(437) to 819. Applications could connect again to the queue manager without a problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there an error in the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` at the same time?

Comment: Note: the queue has a global CSSID, which should be specified at connect; also every message has an own CSSID that can be different to the global setting (eg 1208=utf8, 819=iso8859-1 are plausible choices). Also there are binary operations too that handle bytes, not characters.

Comment: Which version of mq explorer are you running? Which four digit mq 9.1 version are you using on the queue manager? Is there an error in the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` at the same time as the mq explorer error?

Comment: yes, there is the bad conversation error.

Comment: And what versions are involved?

Comment: MQ Explorer: 9.0 ; and MQ Server: 9.1.0.0.  OSlevel 7.1

Answer (score 3):

MQ relies on the AIX base operating system to perform data conversion on its behalf. In order to support Unicode conversion AIX provides several optional filesets:

- bos.iconv.ucs.com     Unicode converters for AIX sets
- bos.iconv.ucs.ebcdic  Unicode converters for EBCDIC sets
- bos.iconv.ucs.pc      Unicode converters for PC sets

You should install these filesets from the AIX operating system installation media if you need to convert data to and from Unicode on your system.

Comment: Already installed this converter bos.iconv.ucs.com Unicode.

Comment: But have you installed all of the ones I told you to install? Since 437 is a PC codepage.

Comment: Hmm, well unfortunatly i dont have the permissions to do that :( . So i have to wait, till the OS admins consider it.